# Android WebView: Page garbled after element removal

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I'm developing Android WebView for a website.
After I entered 10-12 lines of element removals in loadUrl method, page looks garbled. Is there a specific sequence of element removals or modifications?

Here's my code:

```
MyWebViewClient webViewClient = new MyWebViewClient();
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

    webView.loadUrl("javascript: var ele=document.getElementById(\"nav\");\n" +
        "ele.parentNode.removeChild(ele); ele=document.getElementById(\"footer\");\n" +
        "ele.parentNode.removeChild(ele); ele=document.getElementById(\"header\");\n" +
        "ele.parentNode.removeChild(ele); ele=document.getElementById(\"main\");\n" +
        "ele.style.padding=\"0px 0px 0px 0px\"; ele=document.getElementById(\"main\");\n" +
        "document.body.style.margin=\"0px 0px 0px 0px\"; ele=document.getElementById(\"main\");\n" +
        "ele.style.margin=\"0px 0px 0px 0px\";  ele.style.padding=\"10px 15px 15px 15px\"; document.body.style.minWidth=\"350px\"; document.body.style.maxWidth=\"650px\"; " +
        "elements = document.getElementsByClassName(\"status-messages\")\n" +
        "        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {\n" +
        "            elements[i].style.margin=\"0px 0px 0px 0px\";\n" +
        "            elements[i].style.padding=\"0px 0px 0px 0px\";\n" +
        "            elements[i].style.maxHeight=\"700px\";\n" +
        "            elements[i].style.minHeight=\"0px\";\n" +
        "            elements[i].style.maxWidth=\"650px\";\n" +
        "            elements[i].style.minWidth=\"0px\";\n" +
        "        } ele=document.getElementsByTagName(\"body\")[0];\n" +
        "ele.style.maxWidth=\"550px\";\n" +
        "ele.style.minWidth=\"0px\"; ele=document.getElementsByTagName(\"img\")[0];\n" +
        "ele.style.maxWidth=\"450px\";\n" +
        "ele.style.minWidth=\"0px\"; ele=document.getElementById(\"container\");\n" +
        "ele.style.maxWidth=\"550px\";\n" +
        "ele.style.minWidth=\"0px\"; ele=document.getElementById(\"enviroTable\");\n" +
        "ele.style.maxWidth=\"450px\"; elements = document.getElementsByClassName(\"right\");\n" +
        "    while(elements.length > 0)\n" +
        "        elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]); ");
} });
```

I've written this code in onPageFinished method. Is it the right place to do this?

Comment: `onPageFinished` doesn't mean that everything is ready on the page, it only means that WebView has finished loading and parsing the resources of the page. If some of the elements are populated dynamically, they may be just not ready at that moment. The approach you are trying is super fragile. A better approach would be to provide a special stylesheet and then activate its rules on the server.

Comment: I don't have access to server. So I need to do it on Android only. Any other approach for this problem? As you said, how to add special stylesheet on server and make it default for Android devices?

Comment: If you don't have access to server, then obviously, you can't add a special stylesheet there. Then it looks more like monkey patching, and just should be done more carefully. E.g. test in your code for presence of the elements first, before changing them. You can either use `WebView.evaluateJavascript` if you target KitKat+, or just update the title of the page via `document.title` and read it back with `WebView.getTitle()` to communicate the results back to your app.

Comment: @MikhailNaganov Thanks. I checked my JavaScript in Firefox console first, it works perfectly well over there! Just this WebView not working well on it. Android supports all JS methods right? In case of having access to server, for special stylesheet will _@media tag work or need to create whole modified CSS from original one?

Comment: WebView supports JS, but it needs to be enabled with `webView.getSettings().setJavascriptEnabled(true)` before loading the page. Also, WebView is based on Chrome, so you should test in Chrome first, not in FF. Another tip: try using [remote debugging with WebView](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging#debugging-webviews).   I guess, `@media` tag should work.

Comment: @mikhail I already did it that's why page looks gargled. JavaScript works and I'm using WebView client. Should I go for Chrome Client? I didn't know about that Firefox thing. I'll try it on Chrome for sure # Thanks for media tag confirmation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document.readyState worked for me.

I used it as follows:

```
 if(document.readyState === "complete") {
 /* my code */
 }
```

Now it looks exactly the same as on Chrome console.